# Intl.NumberFormat() does not show the Bitcoin Ƀ Symbol

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, bitcoin

the Intl.NumberFormat does not show the bitcoin symbol.

```
CFORMAT_USD = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD', minimumFractionDigits: 8 }); 
CFORMAT_BTC = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BTC', minimumFractionDigits: 8 }); 

console.log(CFORMAT_USD.format(1000));
// 1.000,00000000 $

console.log(CFORMAT_BTC.format(1000));  
// 1.000,00000000 BTC
```

My workaround at the moment

```
console.log(CFORMAT_BTC.format(1000).replace(/BTC/,'Ƀ'));
// 1.000,00000000 Ƀ
```

Is there maybe a better (clean) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol),

> The ISO 4217 currency code for Bitcoin is XBT. However, at the moment it is an unofficial code according to the ISO 4217 standard.

So the correct code should be

```
Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'XBT' })
```

But since it has not made its way to [this list](https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml), browsers didn't implement it yet.

So I would personally use the `XBT` code instead of `BTC` which is completely invalid according to ISO 4217, just in case it makes its way to the list some day.

Answer (score 1):

The standards for crypto are still wobbly, so you could try maintaining or googling a library that would map crypto name to its symbol.
Having that, `NumberFormat.formatToParts` could be used — it provides a way to access the symbol wherever it is in a localised string, like this:

```js
const cryptoSymbols = {
  "ETH": "Ξ",
  "BTC": "₿"
}

function formatCrypto({amount, currency, locale = "en"}) {
  const options = { style: 'currency', currency, minimumFractionDigits: 8 };
  const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, options);
  const parts = numberFormat.formatToParts(amount)

  return parts.reduce((acc, part) => {
    switch (part.type) {
      case 'currency':
        // do whatever you need with the symbol. 
        // here I just replace it with the value from the map
        return acc + cryptoSymbols[currency]
      default:
       return acc + part.value
     }
  }, '') 
}


console.log(formatCrypto({amount: 654321.987, currency: 'ETH'}));
console.log(formatCrypto({amount: 654321.987, currency: 'BTC'}));
```

By the way, the minimum fraction digits may wary, e.g. it's 18 for ETH - I imagine it also needs to be looked up somewhere per currency.