# Intl NuberFormat bad thai currency

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, number-formatting, intl

I'm trying to get some currencyFormatter for the application but I encountered some problem.

I am able to use most of the currency formats with corresponding symbols correctly i.e.

```
var usd = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' }).format(12345);
var euro = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345);
var deEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345);

£12,345.00
€12.345,00
12.345,00 €
```

But when I want to format to Thailand Baht it's not displaying `฿` symbol. Instead, it's THB... Am I doing something wrong or it's not mapped?

```
var thai = new Intl.NumberFormat('th', { style: 'currency', currency: 'THB' }).format(12345);


THB 12,345.00
```

I can replace the string after but it's not convenient for me doing this...

```
var thai = new Intl.NumberFormat('th', { style: 'currency', currency: 'THB' }).format(12345).replace(/\b(\w*THB\w*)\b/, '฿ ');

฿ 12,345.00
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intl.NumberFormat() does not show the Bitcoin Ƀ Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019497/intl-numberformat-does-not-show-the-bitcoin-%c9%83-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('th-TH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'THB' }).format(12345)
```

Output : "฿12,345.00"